# How to require/assert a condition in KNIME?

Tags: java, knime

If I want to specify preconditions on the input arguments, what is the idiomatic way when developing KNIME nodes?

Using `assert(condition, message)` might be efficient and simple, thought its check depends on the VM argument `-ea`.

Manually checking with `if (condition) throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);` seems better, but it does not provide extra semantic information when only checking for `null`s for example.

There is also the `org.knime.core.node.InvalidSettingsException` exception. Should that be used for this purpose?

Is there a collection of methods that should be used in KNIME?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a recommended way to signal incorrect inputs, there are specialized methods in `org.knime.core.node.util.CheckUtils` (from the bundle org.knime.core.util). It has methods for:

- non-`null` checks: `checkNotNull`, `checkArgumentNotNull`, `checkSettingNotNull`
- arguments: `checkArgument`
- state: `checkState`
- setting (from UI or flow variable): `checkSetting`
- files: `checkDestinationFile`, `checkSourceFile`, `checkDestinationDirectory`

These allow using templates in the messages which only expanded when the check fails.

You can find example usages with [this query](https://github.com/knime/knime-core/search?l=Java&q=checkutils&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: And yes, you should throw `InvalidSettingsException` in the Node Model `configure` method.  It is also worth looking at some of the settings models themselves, for example, `SettingsModelIntegerBounded` which constrain the input within the settings model preventing the user entering something invalid in the dialog

Comment: @SteveR probably I was unclear, but `checkSetting` can be used for that. (It is a checked exception.)